# app/code folders missing in magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

The tutorial I'm working through: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2
does not explain what to do with the missing app/code directory.

I got Magento by compressed archive and I understand — the vendor directory is equivalent to `app/code`. I don't understand what this means. Can I create the directory in my computer simply by right-clicking inside the magento  folder an choosing *New > Folder*. I created an `app/code` folder directory like this:

```
xampp>htdocs>magento>vender>magento>app>code
```

Should I do this?

```
xampp>htdocs>magento>vender>app>code
```

Or?

```
xampp>htdocs>magento>vender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app folder goes in the base magento directory.

```
xampp>htdocs>magento>app>code
```

Comment: This is Magento 2. app/code for version 2 has been removed from the base Magento directory. I have been told the vendor directory is equivalent to app/code.

Comment: Just create the folders that don't exist. The vendor directory is used for modules / themes that are installed using composer.

Comment: customizations goes to app/code while any third party components and the Magento application itself are stored under the vendor dir. Usually if you are using git this vendor dir is typacilly added to .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 app folder is already but need to create the (code) folder for own customization.

htdocs/magento/vendor/magento contain all  base files for magento.These all are magento core modules.

Comment: Do I have create app/code folders? If so, where do I create the folders?

Comment: In magento root installation .